# How to use access data in a table that's connected thru a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a section of a website that should be accessible to only certain users. I was thinking of this table structure for access control. Is there any other way with a better performance?

```
**Users**
id    |   Name   |   age
39    |   Peter  |   24 
40    |   Alan   |   15


**Sections**
id    |   Name   |   description
1     |  Games   |   flash games
2     |  Bank    |  bank access


**AccessControl**
id   |   user_id   |  section_id
1    |     39      |    1
2    |     39      |    2
3    |     40      |    1
```

How would the SELECT be to get all the sections Peter (id: 39) can access?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Sections where section_id in (SELECT section_id from AccessControl where user_id=39)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying:

```
select s.* from Users u, Sections s, AccessControl ac where
u.id = 39 and
u.id = ac.user_id and
ac.section_id = s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question; Stack Overflow is not the correct place. It is more suitable for [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). For your second question:

```
SELECT s.name, s.description, u.name
FROM Sections s, Users u
INNER JOIN AccessControl ac
    ON ( ac.user_id = u.id
        AND ac.section_id = s.id )
WHERE u.id = 39
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sections
JOIN AccessControl ON Sections.id = AccessControl.section_id
JOIN Users ON Users.id = AccessControl.user_id
WHERE Users.id = 39
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM access_control
JOIN sections ON sections.id = access_control.section_id
WHERE access_control.user_id =39
```